# Color group for lavender

Tags: color, color-theory

I have to group the colors in as few groups as possible. For example, I would group *gold* and *khaki* under *yellow.*

In which group should I put *lavender?*

My color groups are the following:

- Pink
- Red
- Orange
- Yellow
- Green
- Blue
- Brown
- White
- Grey

Comment: Could you add some context? Where and why do you need to do this? Your color groups are pretty limited. Where for example do orange and purple fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would list Lavender under the Blue group.

Comment: Is that fine with my `color groups`?

Comment: I would assume it is. Not sure why i got a down vote, since this is obviously a subjective question to which you can only answer subjectively :)

Answer (score 5):

Even though I would if asked categorize Lavender under Blue like @Lucian it is worth noting that:

Colors can not really be categorized this way. For example the color Khaki depending on person, and exact composition of the Khaki, could be categorized under green. And Lavender could be under Red depending on what hue you think Lavender is (altough most would put that it is blue) There is a really good write up on this particular subject on XKCD blog under the header **[Color Survey Results](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/)**

So the take after reading the survey summary should be. Be very careful with naming of colors. Not many people agree with you, and that nobody knows how to spell Fuchsia. There is not much point in trying to place the more varied names in a system as people do not agree with the hue let alone what super category that hue belongs to!